# let $L_f, L_g, L_{f+g}$ be the lower integral of $f, g, and f+g$. Prove that $L_{f+g}\ge L_f+L_g$

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

let $f,g$ be two bounded function on $[a,b]$, let $L_f, L_g, L_{f+g}$ be the lower integral of $f, g, and f+g$. Prove that $L_{f+g}\ge L_f+L_g$

I don't know how to start

Comment: You can start with the definition of lower integral and use the properties of integrating functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you *should* attack any problem like this (i.e. a problem so basic that looking at pure definitions is a productive route): Going from the definition of lower integrals, we are led to look at lower sums (because the lower integral is defined as a limit of lower sums with finer and finer partitions). Since lower sums sum over a finite number of intervals, we are first led to look at what happens on a single interval. Then we work our way back. This is what happens:

On an interval $[i, j]$, let $l_{f}, l_g, l_{f+g}$ be the infimum of $f, g$ and $f+g$ respectively. We have that $l_f + l_g \leq l_{f+g}$ (show this).

With this, you can show that the lower sums $L'_f, L'_g, L'_{f+g}$ for any finite partition of $[a, b]$ satisfy $L'_f + L'_g \leq L'_{f+g}$ (show this too).

Now take the limit as the partitions get finer and finer. The inequality still stands (show this as well).

Now you're done.

Comment: Very well written answer which serves as a guide and motivates OP to work the full solution himself. (+1)